# Multiple Kafka Producers in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-kafka

I have a use case which requires me to have multiple Kafka Producers (based on the configuration). i.e., if my configuration has 3 tenants who want to receive data, I want to spin up 3 producers (all three write to 3 different clusters).

I tried with my Kafka configuration to be:

```
  @Bean
  @Primary
  public Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates() {
    log.info("setting up kafka templates");
    final String ids = configuration.getIds();
    Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates = new HashMap<>();

    for (String id : ids.split(",")) {
      kafkaTemplates.put(id, kafkaTemplate(id));
    }
    return kafkaTemplates;
  }

  private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate(String id) {
    log.info("setting up kafka template");
    try {
      Properties producerProperties = new Properties();
      try (InputStream kins = Files.newInputStream(new File("/opt/user-secrets/", id + ".properties").toPath())) {
        producerProperties.load(kins);
      } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
      }
      Map props = producerProperties;
      Map<String, Object> props1 = (Map<String, Object>) props;
      ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory = new DefaultKafkaProducerFactory<>(props1);
      return new KafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory);
    } catch (Exception e) {
      log.error("e {}", e.getMessage(), e);
      throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
  }
```

This is resulting in a NPE on `kafkaTemplates.get(id)`, when I try to access the KafkaTemplate in the Producer service:

```
@Service
@Slf4j
@Getter
@Setter
public class KafkaProducerService {


  private final Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates;

  private Schema avroSchema;

  public KafkaProducerService(Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates) {
    this.kafkaTemplates = kafkaTemplates;
  }

  public void produce(String id, String topic, String key, VehicleHeartbeat message) {
    GenericRecord record = generateAvroRecord(message);
    log.info("generic record: {}", record);
    kafkaTemplates.get(id).send(topic, key, record.toString());
  }
```

How do I do this with spring Kafka?

Comment: Where exactly is your NPE? `kafkaTemplates.get(id)` or `get(id).send()` meaning is your templates map null or the element in the map with the given id null?

Comment: Sorry, updated my question

Comment: whats in the map?

Comment: It should have a map of producerID (some unique ID to identify a producer) and KafkaTemplate<String, String>. But I see that it has only kafkaTemplate as key - no idea why.

Comment: So the `kafkaTemplates` map is `null` in the service, did you annotate your `KafkaProducerService` with `@Service` annotation so that the `kafkaTemplates` map gets automatically injected via constructor injection, because it doesn't appear in the code you shared?

Comment: I actually did. Its not working even after that. Like you said, the bean is not getting injected. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: What you could try is replace the `@Bean` with: `@Bean("myKafkaTemplatesMap")` and then in the constructor: `public KafkaProducerService(@Qualifier("myKafkaTemplatesMap") Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates)` (you name the bean and then qualify it in the constructor parameter with the same name)

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably a clash with some other `Map` bean.

What you could try is replace the `@Bean` on `kafkaTemplates` method like this:

```java
@Bean("myKafkaTemplatesMap")
@Primary
public Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates() {
    ...
}
```

and then in the service constructor you qualify it with the same name, this way you make sure the correct bean gets injected:

```java
@Service
public class KafkaProducerService {

    public KafkaProducerService(@Qualifier("myKafkaTemplatesMap") Map<String, KafkaTemplate<String, String>> kafkaTemplates) {
        this.kafkaTemplates = kafkaTemplates;
    }
}
```